# jdbctemplate Query : Exception in thread "File Watcher" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: memory-leaks, spring-boot, mariadb, heap-memory, jdbctemplate

im getting an out of memory error, that happends when i run a 500k+ results query.
ive tried to a resultset to use "pointer" to the db results.
and setted fetch size to 1000.
what else can i do?
Im using spring boot, and maria db driver, thanks.

### ExcelComponent.java

```
@Component
public class ExcelComponent {

    @Autowired
    DatabaseChooser databaseChooser;

    public String create(DbModel dbModel, boolean isTemp) {
        JdbcTemplate jdbc = databaseChooser.getJdbcTemplateByDatabaseId(dbModel);
        return createFile(query, jdbc, isTemp);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private String createFile(String query, JdbcTemplate jdbc) {
        PreparedStatementSet psc = new PreparedStatementSet(query);
        jdbc.query(psc, new ResultSetExcelWriter(options));
        return "";
}
```

DatabaseChooser.java

```
@Component
public class DatabaseChooser {

    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplateByDatabaseId(SettingsDbsModel dbModel){
        DataSource dataSource = createDatasource(dbModel);
        try {
            dataSource.getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource, true);
        jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(100);
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }
```

ResultSetExcelWriter.java

```
public class ResultSetExcelWriter implements ResultSetExtractor{
    ExcelWriterNew writer;

    public ResultSetExcelWriter(WriterOptions csvWriterOptions) {

        writer = new ExcelWriterNew(csvWriterOptions);
    }

    @Override
    public Object extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, Da

    taAccessException {

            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getObject(1));
            }

            writer.make();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Patient:  "It hurts when I do this".  Doctor:  "Well, don't do that".

Comment: Seriously, what will your program do with 500K rows?  Can the data be summarized in SQL, so that only a few rows need to be sent back to the program?  Could you write a Stored Program to do the work?  Etc.

Comment: Or break it into 1K-row chunks.  Or ...

Comment: The rows should be written one by one to excel / csv.
Without being saving to the memory - for preventing a memory leak , i tried to iterate the result with cursor ResultSet - but still its bloating the memory.

Comment: Which one is the main memory hog?  Java?  Excel?  MySQL?

Comment: Java. i made what you said as a walkaround - im now iterating 100k rows queries set. with LIMIT OFFSET.

Comment: Don't use `OFFSET`; "remember where you left off".  Also, don't do more than 10K at a time.

Comment: Why not to use OFFSET?
and, 10k rows at a time is 10 * 10  * 10 times to run the query for getting 1 million rows.. 1000 times to run a queries is too much.

Comment: LIMIT 0,1000 (with a an index on the ORDER BY) will read 1K rows.  LIMIT 1000,1000 will read 2K rows and deliver 1K. ...  LIMIT 499000,1000 will read 500K rows!  The total is 500*500K = 250M rows read.

Comment: On the other hand, if you "remember where you left off" and do `WHERE id > $left_off ORDER BY id LIMIT 1000`, it is only 1K each, for a total of 500K.